# Usar threads ou programas separados?

Tags: linux, thread, sistema-operacional

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que envolve três (talvez mais) processos que são executados simultaneamente: um servidor HTTP, um logger e outro que executará o código principal.

A priori, uma solução simples para fazer isso é utilizando três threads, um para cada tarefa do programa. Essa é uma solução bem simples e que me permite trocar informações entre os threads de forma bem tranquila, caso seja necessário.

No entanto, essas três tarefas podem ser executadas de forma bastante independente e poderiam ser feitas em três programas diferentes, ao invés de três threads em um único programa.

A minha dúvida então está nessa questão: qual a diferença entre essas duas abordagens? Qual seria a mais recomendável, considerando que a terceira é a thread principal?

**Considerações:** a aplicação rodará em um sistema Linux bem puro (só com o essencial instalado) e o hardware é um [BeagleBone Black](http://beagleboard.org/black).

Comment: Depende um pouco da linguagem usada mas meu *default* costuma ser separar. Uso *threads* só quando não compensa passar dados para outro processo, onde o processamento precisa de uma resposta muita rápida e a passagem entre processos vai custar muito. Pode ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1946/%C3%89-sempre-garantido-que-uma-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-m%C3%BAltiplas-threads-rode-mais-r%C3%A1pido-que

Comment: @bigown Devo utilizar threads do C++11, se eu for fazer com threads. Vou conferir o link. Obrigado.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Comment: @EduardoSeixas Basicamente é uma questão de projetos. Não há muita diferença entre as abordagens. A principal diferente é a comunicação, usando threads você compartilha o mesmo contexto e memória no SO, programas separados não.

Comment: Entendi. Então crie uma reposta e marque-a como aceita, assim sua pergunta não fica órfã e pode ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sempre é aconselhável usar processos separados. (Hoje em dia, com a tendência de microservices, a "moda" é utilizar até máquinas virtuais separadas, mas isto foge ao escopo da pergunta.)

Não vejo vantagens na utilização de threads no seu caso de uso, porque a troca de informações entre threads envolve questões de sincronização é sempre um problema por si só. Parece fácil mas nunca é. O custo de fazer isso com segurança é o mesmo que passar mensagens entre processos separados (o uso de memória compartilhada, que de fato é mais rápido, poderia ser justificado em aplicações científicas, que não é o caso).

Algumas vantagens de processos separados:

a) se um processo morrer, ele pode ser reiniciado sem afetar os outros, já a morte de uma thread mata o processo todo, incluindo as demais threads.

b) a separação de tarefas em processos separados aumenta a segurança.

c) Cada processo é mais fácil de reutilizar em outra aplicação.

d) A atualização de um software (e.g. o servidor HTTP) pode ser feito sem parar os outros.

Answer (score -1):

Depende muito de como vão ser as interações entre os programas ou threads. É basicamente o que foi dito nos comentários: "A principal diferente é a comunicação, usando *threads* você compartilha o mesmo contexto e memória no SO, programas separados não." Isso implica que se você fizer em programas separados, para trocar informações e dados através de um arquivo, por exemplo, ou mesmo através de `socket`s, mas de forma local.