# Multi-core CPUs - Por que minha aplicação não utiliza todos os núcleos do processador?

Tags: java, .net, delphi, delphi-7, multi-core

Tenho uma duvida que não consigo encontrar uma resposta convincente.

Há uma aplicação desenvolvida em Delphi 7, e em uma rotina extremamente complexa (que demora cerca de 2 horas) reparamos que só é utilizado para a mesma o primeiro núcleo do processador, no caso um Intel Core-i7 (8 núcleo), e os demais núcleos permanecem ociosos (pelo menos é que o monitor de recursos do Windows demonstra).

A respeito disso tenho vários questionamentos, sendo os principais os seguintes:

- Por que isso ocorre?
- Isso é um problema do Delphi 7, ou do Delphi?
- Isso pode ser resolvido utilizando Delphi 7?
- Outras tecnologia como .net e Java, já estão preparadas para utilizar de forma eficiente Multi-core CPUs?
- No caso de outras tecnologia como .net e Java. É necessário fazer algo na aplicação ou isso já ocorrerá de forma automática e gerenciada pelo Framework?

Comment: Na sua aplicação tem várias threads ou apenas uma?

Comment: Como  o @Math comentou, tu já tentou rodar esse processo demorado em mais de uma thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630686/delphi-7-how-to-implement-multi-threading

Comment: Para usar todos os CORES, sua programação tem que ter sido pensada para isso. Mesmo em .Net deve-se usar bibliotecas e técnicas específicas para tirar proveito de todos os núcleos

Comment: @Math, somente uma unica theads, mas se trata de um processo único, que não poderia ser divido em threads. Mas uma mesma thead não poderia mandar instruções para todos o núcleos do processador?

Comment: Até onde sei você tem que dividir em multi threads para que cada uma seja rodada em um núcleo, e talvez ainda tenha que fazer algo mais além disso. Não sou expert em threads, mas com certeza se puser uma única pra thread para rodar ela não se dividirá em vários núcleos, pois não tem como o processador fazer paralelismo do seu código se seu código está todo, digamos, sequencial.

Comment: É necessário que você modifique sua aplicação utilizando threads de sistema para que sua aplicação utilize mais de um core. Isso não é uma limitação ou problema do Delphi.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101

Answer (score 9):

**Algoritmo Serial vs Algoritmo Paralelo**

Para conseguir resolver seu problema, vc vai precisar alterar seu algoritmo.

Hoje o que você tem é uma aplicação que executa toda sua lógica em uma única thread que será executada por um único processador. A isso chamados de **algoritmo serial** ou sequencial.

O que significa dizer que toda sua lógica é executada de maneira sequencial. Você teria que reescrever parte da sua aplicação dividindo-a em subtasks - subtarefas, e entregá-las a threads - este seria o algoritmo paralelo. Um adendo não é possível paralelizar todo o seu algoritmo, você apenas consegue dividir até um certo ponto.

O número de threads deve ser o número de processadores disponíveis e para cada thread você submete suas tasks. Cada thread é executada por um processador. Não confunda computação paralela com programação concorrente.

> Outras tecnologia como .net e Java, já estão preparadas para utilizar
>   de forma eficiente Multi-core CPUs?

Java sempre proveu APIs e frameworks para programação concorrente e computação paralela.A partir do Java 1.5 um framework chamado [Executor Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) foi adicionado. Ele oferece diversas classes utilitárias, interfaces, métodos para a fabricação de Pools de Thread e métodos de submissão de tasks.

Já no Java 1.7 ganhamos o [Fork/Join framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html). Ao qual permite que você programe um algoritmo definindo ***Thresholds*** de processamento, que são limites, quando esse limite é atingido você querbra a tarefa em dois - Fork. Uma vez que ela é executada e que as outras tarefas são completadas, você faz o jois delas para o resultado final. Interessantemente, este framework implementa um algorítimo chamada ***work-stealing***. Trata-se de uma técnica onde quando uma thread termina de executar sua task ela rouba a task de outra thread que ainda não terminou sua execução.

**Last but not least**

Se assumir o projeto de migrar um novo modelo de execução, recomendo que você estude a [lei de Amdahl's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) que prediz o máximo de tempo que é possível se optimizar um programa utilizando múltiplos processadores.

Fontes:
Algoritmo serial: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_algorithm

Algoritmo paralelo: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_algorithm

Computação paralela: https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Parallel_computing

Comment: Vale apena mencionar que embora Java permita a computação paralela e concorrente, nada é mágico e você precisa aprender a utilizar várias threads e etc... O mesmo é possível no Delphi.

Comment: tem tb uma abstração em cima de thread, que á o modelos de Atores - Actors Model, simplifica bastante. O Framework Akka pode ajudar.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model

Answer (score 0):

Explicando uma forma **BEM** simplificada as diferenças entre os modelos de execução:

**Multitasking:**

- Vários processos em um núcleo.
- Rodam de forma concorrente.

[image: Multiprocessing]

**Multiprocessing:**

- Vários processos em vários núcleos.
- Rodam de forma paralela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Multithreading**:

- Um processo usando várias threads.
- Computação é dividida entre os núcleos
- PS: (Rodará em paralelo ou não, depende do seu código e do hardware)

[image: Multithreading]