# Stream() e parallelStreams()

Tags: java, java-8, stream

Vi que a performance utilizando *lambdas* e *streams* é muito melhor do que usando laços de repetição, portanto tento utilizar o máximo possível. 
Minha dúvida é **quando devo usar** Streams ou ParallelStreams? Como ocorre esse paralelismo de streams?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A API de Streams disponível a partir do Java 8, passou a trazer diversos benefícios, vamos primeiro definir o algoritmo serial vs o algoritmo paralelo.

Recomendo a leitura desta pergunta, a minha resposta procura explorar estes dois paradigmas da computação: [Multi-core CPUs - Por que minha aplicação não utiliza todos os núcleos do processador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/70769/multi-core-cpus-por-que-minha-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-n%C3%A3o-utiliza-todos-os-n%C3%BAcleos-do-proces/70989#70989)

Agora que entendemos paralelismo, vamos para Streams...

**De acordo com a Oracle**

Você pode executar `Stream` em série ou em paralelo (*Serial ou Parallel*). Quando uma `Stream` é executada em paralelo, java particiona ou divide as `Stream`s em várias substreams. Operações de agregação iteram e processam esses substreams em paralelo e, em seguida, combinam os resultados.

Fonte: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html

**Em outras palavras**

A intenção da *parallel stream*, é permitir que o processamento seja dividido entre os processadores de sua máquina, por exemplo, se você precisa ordenar uma grande `Collection`, isto pode ser feito de maneira serial, e consequentemente por uma única `Thread`, ou de maneira paralela, com duas ou mais `Threads`.

O que significa dizer que a `Collection` é quebrada em duas subcollections, e ordenada em paralelo, o que em tese diminui o tempo gasto pela metade.

O ponto de grande importância é: nem sempre isso é verdade. Até mesmo por que isto pode depender da quantidade de processadores que você tem.

- *Parallel Streams* podem fazer seu programa mais rápido, ou não, e até mesmo mais lento.
- Depende de quais operações em `Stream`s você utiliza, nem todas são de fato paralelizadas

Fontes:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html

http://java.dzone.com/articles/whats-wrong-java-8-part-iii

Comment: Gostei da explicação do parallel stream.