# Por que um FOR dá loop mais rápido do que 10 FORs em conjunto?

Tags: java, multithreading, paralelismo, for

Eu fiz um `for` sozinho contar até 1000000 (mandando 1 mensagem a cada *loop*) e ele demorou 14 segundos.

```
public class main 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
{
    long init  = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

    Thread ataque = ataque();
    ataque.start();
    ataque.join();

    long end  = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    long diff = end - init;
    System.out.println("Demorou " + (diff / 1000) + " segundos");
}

static int limite = 1000000;
static int for1 = 0;
static int for2 = (limite / 10);
static int for3 = for2 + for2; 
static int for4 = for3 + for2; 
static int for5 = for4 + for2; 
static int for6 = for5 + for2;
static int for7 = for6 + for2;
static int for8 = for7 + for2;
static int for9 = for8 + for2;

public static Thread ataque()
{
    Thread t = new Thread() 
    { 
        @Override 
        public void run() 
        {
            for(int i = 0; i <= limite; i++)
            {   
                System.out.println(i + " de " + limite); 
            }
        }
    };
    return t;
}
}
```

Logo após eu dividi esses `for` em 10 diferentes executando simultaneamente 10000000 (mandando 1 mensagem a cada *loop*) de *loops*, demorou 15 segundos.

```
public class main 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
{
    long init  = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    Thread t1 = ataque1();
    Thread t2 = ataque2();
    Thread t3 = ataque3();
    Thread t4 = ataque4();
    Thread t5 = ataque5();
    Thread t6 = ataque6();
    Thread t7 = ataque7();
    Thread t8 = ataque8();
    Thread t9 = ataque9();
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    t4.start();
    t5.start();
    t6.start();
    t7.start();
    t8.start();
    t9.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
    t5.join();
    t6.join();
    t7.join();
    t8.join();
    t9.join();

    long end  = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    long diff = end - init;
    System.out.println("Demorou " + (diff / 1000) + " segundos");
}

static int limite = 1000000;
static int for1 = 0;
static int for2 = (limite / 10);
static int for3 = for2 + for2; 
static int for4 = for3 + for2; 
static int for5 = for4 + for2; 
static int for6 = for5 + for2;
static int for7 = for6 + for2;
static int for8 = for7 + for2;
static int for9 = for8 + for2;

public static Thread ataque1()
{
    Thread t = new Thread() 
    { 
        @Override 
        public void run() 
        {
            for(int i = for1 ; i < for2; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(i + " de " + limite); 
            }
        }
    };
    return t;
}
public static Thread ataque2()
{
    Thread t = new Thread() 
    { 
        @Override 
        public void run() 
        {   
            for(int i = for2; i < for3; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(i + " de " + limite); 
            }
        }
    };
    return t;

}
public static Thread ataque3()
{
    Thread t = new Thread() 
    { 
        @Override 
        public void run() 
        {
            for(int i = for3; i < for4; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(i + " de " + limite); 
            }
        }
    };
    return t;
}
public static Thread ataque4()
{
    Thread t = new Thread() 
    { 
        @Override 
        public void run() 
        {
            for(int i = for4; i <= for5; i++)
            {   
                System.out.println(i + " de " + limite); 
            }
        }
    };
    return t;
}
public static Thread ataque5()
{
    Thread t = new Thread() 
    { 
        @Override 
        public void run() 
        {
            for(int i = for5; i < for6; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(i + " de " + limite); 
            }
        }
    };
    return t;
}
public static Thread ataque6()
{
    Thread t = new Thread() 
    { 
        @Override 
        public void run() 
        {
            for(int i = for6; i < for7; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(i + " de " + limite); 
            }
        }
    };
    return t;
}
public static Thread ataque7()
{
    Thread t = new Thread() 
    { 
        @Override 
        public void run() 
        {
            for(int i = for7; i < for8; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(i + " de " + limite); 
            }
        }
    };
    return t;
}
public static Thread ataque8()
{
    Thread t = new Thread() 
    { 
        @Override 
        public void run() 
        {
            for(int i = for8; i < for9; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(i + " de " + limite); 
            }
        }
    };
    return t;
}
public static Thread ataque9()
{
    Thread t = new Thread() 
    { 
        @Override 
        public void run() 
        {
            for(int i = for9; i < limite; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(i + " de " + limite); 
            }
        }
    };
    return t;
}
}
```

Por que mesmo ele estando "10 vezes mais eficiente" continua dando um resultado pior?

Comment: Não é assim que funciona @LucasCarezia
Cada Thread só pode ser executada por um processador. Vc tem 10 processadores na sua máquina?
Leia esta resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/70769/multi-core-cpus-por-que-minha-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-n%C3%A3o-utiliza-todos-os-n%C3%BAcleos-do-proces/70989#70989

Recomendo tb que vc de uma revisada em computacão paralela.

Comment: Nem sempre um algoritimo pode ser mais rápido através do uso de computacão paralela, existem vários fatores que estarão envolvidos para determinar o quão mais rápido um programa pode ser:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basicamente você precisa ler esta [pergunta/resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101) pra entender.

Em grande parte das situações dividir o trabalho deixa mais lento mesmo. Não existe milagre, se você não tiver recursos para a execução ser efetivamente paralela, você apenas ganhará uma sobrecarga de trabalho para administrar as diversas tarefas sendo comutadas (paralelizar sempre terá esse custo, mas se tiver mais processadores e não tiver uma dependência pode dar ganho, ele só não será linear).

Fora isto, eu não sei bem como se faz *benchmark* em Java, não sei se esta forma de medir o tempo é a mais recomendada. Já vi muitos testes produzirem resultados errados porque a forma da medição estava errada.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado, esclareceu minhas duvidas.