# Qual é o máximo de threads suportadas pelo Java EE?

Tags: java, java-ee, thread, multithreading, scheduler

Estou analisando como reescrever a arquitetura de um programa em Java gostaria de saber quantas threads o escalonador (*scheduler*) suporta? ou então como posso inferir essa quantidade me baseando no poder de processamento do meu PC/Servidor/Cluster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não conheço um problema no qual onde um grande número de threads possa ajudar. Você pode ter milhares de threads na maioria dos computadores modernos e até dezenas de milhares em servidores mais potentes, mas isso não vai ajudar em nada dependendo do problema que está resolvendo. O @Maniero já falou um pouco sobre isso.

Além disso, um limite ainda depende da JVM que está usando. Em um ambiente controlado, você mesmo pode medir e determinar um limite teórico, afinal sempre pode variar dependendo do uso que a máquina está tendo ao longo do tempo.

Crie um programa que faça o seguinte:

1. Instancie uma thread e carregue a quantidade média de dados que você pretende usar em cada uma.
2. Recupere a quantidade de memória usada e grave num log esse valor junto com a quantidade de threads criadas até o momento
3. Repita os passos 1 e 2, criando sempre novas threads e armazenando os valores

Deixe o programa rodar por um tempo, jogue os valores salvos numa planilha e você terá uma relação da quantidade de threads com a memória utilizada.

Note que nada disso tem a ver com a performance, pois quando há muito mais threads que CPUs o desempenho tende a cair devido à sobrecarga do escalonamento.

Em trabalhos de paralelismo que já fiz, foi preciso experimentar  o problema com diferentes números de threads para determinar a quantidade ótima. Mas tudo isso ainda envolve detalhes de como as threads se comunicam e consolidam o resultado ao final.

Sugiro que formule seu problema por completo em uma nova pergunta e questione sobre sua abordagem, se ela estaria adequada, ao invés de questionar sobre um detalhe técnico que provavelmente não será determinante na sua implementação.

Answer (score 3):

Esta informação não é relevante. A arquitetura de processamento e o sistema operacional é que vai determinar isto. Pode haver um limite teórico, mas o que determinará o limite é a praticidade.

Só é possível saber quantas *threads* usar testando. Mesmo assim não é fácil achar um equilíbrio em muitas situações. O que pode ser bom em um momento pode não ser mais em outro.

Duas *threads* pode ser muito. Milhares pode eventualmente ser perfeitamente suportável.

Em casos em que a *thread* realmente é a solução é comum o número ideal ser igual ou próximo do número de processadores lógicos.

Produzir código paralelo de forma correta e eficiente não é algo simples. É muito fácil errar quando sai dos casos triviais. Tenha certeza que terá ganho e que o esforço compensa. Há muitos casos que houve ganho acabando com o uso de *thread*. Para ajudar existem algumas bibliotecas de mais alto nível que facilitam um pouco o trabalho cuidando de parte da complexidade.

Você pode [entender melhor nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101).