# Atualizar a label sem travar o programa

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer

Preciso atualizar a minha `label` a todo momento quando uso o `timer` ele atualiza, mas ele trava o programa

#### Program.cs

```
public static String Uso()
{

    ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("win32_processor");
    ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
    String Id = String.Empty;
    foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
    {
        Id = mo.Properties["LoadPercentage"].Value.ToString();
        break;
    }

    return Id;
}
```

#### Form1.cs

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label42.Text = Program.HardwareInfo.Uso();
}
```

Eu não consigo achar uma maneira que ele atualize a informação do uso do processador e deixa o meu programa rodando normalmente.

Comment: Apesar de poder dar uma melhorada, isto não deve bloquear o programa. Como está configurado o `Timer`? Qual o tempo mínimo que precisa que atualize?

Comment: Experimentou colocar isso em uma thread? Não sei se entendi bem a sua dúvida, mas como ele trava, eu experimentaria colocar em uma thread. http://www.macoratti.net/10/09/c_thd1.htm

Comment: Ele deve estar usando o `Interval` como 1 segundo ou menos. @bigown

Comment: Cadê a implementação do timer?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

Isso deve estar acontecendo porque o intervalo do timer (`timer.Interval`) está muito curto e a *thread* principal fica travada sempre executando o evento do timer.

Você pode fazer isso numa thread a parte apenas trocando o `timer` que estás usando ([`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)) por um [`System.Timers.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx).

Isso deve funcionar para o seu caso. Observe que o evento agora é o [`Elapsed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx) e não mais o `Tick`

```
public timer_Elapsed(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e){
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => label42.Text = Program.HardwareInfo.Uso()));
}
```

---

Tem outras coisas que eu melhoria nisso, talvez até nem usasse um timer. Mas isso deve ser o suficiente para resolver seu problema sem mexer muito no código.

Answer (score 3):

Não há nada errado com o que está fazendo. Pelo menos não no trecho mostrado. A configuração do `Timer` pode estar errado. Tenha certeza que está correto vendo o [exemplo na documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer.start?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_Timer_Start).

O *timer* usado é o correto para o Windows Forms. Não existe razão para usar *thread* aí. Nem mesmo assincronia parece adequada. A função do *timer* é justamente chamar o método estabelecido. Se ele executa rápido, e este tipo de tarefa deve executar muito rápido, senão ela é inviável, tudo vai funcionar quase sem perceber. [Qualquer mecanismo tentando usar *thread* só pioraria a situação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101).

Talvez todo o formulário esteja travando a aplicação. Aí é outro problema. Na verdade é problema do que está rodando a mais, porque o formulário é soberano e ele precisa permitir que outras partes executem livremente. Mas só estou especulando, já que não há detalhes na pergunta.

Eu só mudaria a forma como captura a informação. Não usaria WMI. Eu criaria uma propriedade no formulário para manter um contador de performance do Windows:

```
private PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
```

E aí teria:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) => label42.Text = cpuCounter.NextValue().ToString();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/ChangeByTick.cs).

Talvez precise dar uma adaptada ao que precisa, mas a base é essa.