# A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato incorreto.Operadores

Tags: c#, .net, string

Olá, sou iniciante em programação e estou tentando mostrar ao usuário o tanto de memória RAM que está sendo consumida no momento, estou usando o seguinte código que não está apontando nem um erro ao compilar apenas quando dou Start ele diz:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava
>   em um formato incorreto.

e da break nesta linha:

```
double ram = Convert.ToInt32(Program.HardwareInfo.RAM());
```

**Form1.cs**

```
    PerformanceCounter ram = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes", null);

public string RAM_TIE()
        {
            float ran = ram.NextValue();
            int run = (int)ran;
            return run.ToString();

        }

    public string RAMU_TIE()
    {

        int ramu = Convert.ToInt32(RAM_TIE());
        double ram = Convert.ToInt32(Program.HardwareInfo.RAM());
        double sub = ram - ramu;
        return sub.ToString();

    }
```

**Program.cs**

```
    public static string RAM()
    {
        ManagementScope oMs = new ManagementScope();
        ObjectQuery oQuery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT Capacity FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory");
        ManagementObjectSearcher oSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(oMs, oQuery);
        ManagementObjectCollection oCollection = oSearcher.Get();

        long MemSize = 0;
        long mCap = 0;

        // 
        foreach (ManagementObject obj in oCollection)
        {
            mCap = Convert.ToInt64(obj["Capacity"]);
            MemSize += mCap;
        }
        MemSize = (MemSize / 1024) / 1024;
        return MemSize.ToString() + "MB";
    }
```

Comment: Resolvi responder porque acho que este código por ser muito mais simples do que é.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O método RAM() retorna uma string que não é convertível em um inteiro.

Repare nesta linha desse método:

```
return MemSize.ToString() + "MB";
```

se alterar para:

```
return MemSize.ToString();
```

deverá funcionar.

Comment: Muito obrigado ramaral! você solucionou o meu problema, é uma pena eu não ter repução 15 para dar a resposta como útil!

Comment: No caso de respostas a perguntas suas não há essa limitação, você pode votar nas resposta que achar úteis. e aceitar uma delas

Comment: Obrigado pelo aviso @ramaral!

Answer (score 4):

se você não quiser alterar o seu `RAM()`, você pode usar um overload do `TrimEnd` que recebe um array de char pra tirar do final, que seria o seu "MB" assim:

```
var ram = Convert.ToInt32(Program.HardwareInfo.RAM().TrimEnd("MB".ToCharArray()));
```

Answer (score 3):

Você está pegando algo que é `long` transformando em `string` para depois transformá-lo em `int` e jogar em uma variável `double`. Isto é muito louco e não faz sentido.

Mude o retorno de `RAM()` para:

```
return MemSize;
```

Obviamente o método retornará um `long` e não mais uma `string`.

E na chamada deste método use:

```
public string RAMU_TIE() {
    return (Program.HardwareInfo.RAM() - RAM_TIE()).ToString();
}
```

Bem mais simples, né?

Dependendo de onde vai usar isto, o `ToString()` é desnecessário (mudando o tipo do método, claro.

Eu faria o mesmo no `RAM_TIE()`. E ainda mudaria algumas outras coisas. Entre elas a forma de pegar esses valores, conforme já demonstrei em [outra resposta para o AP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/97686/101). Na verdade não entendi porque hora pega de um jeito e hora pega de outro. Aconselho fortemente usar a maneira usada no `RAMU_TIE()`.

```
public int RAM_TIE() {
    return ram.NextValue();
}
```

Ficou tão simples que talvez nem precise do método. Eu deixaria se ele tivesse um significado semântico importante, mas não parece ser o caso, o nome nem diz pra que serve este método. Ele é fora de padrão.

Se fizer o mesmo esquema no método `RAM()`, provavelmente ele também deixa de ser necessário, aí o `RAMU_TIE()` só precisaria disto:

```
(ram.NextValue() - ramTie.NextValue()).ToString();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/RamFormat.cs).

Deixo para o AP exercitar isto. O código pode ser absurdamente mais simples do que é atualmente.

Answer (score 1):

> Só pra não excluir a resposta, o que respondi está errado, é possível
>   sim armazenar um `int` em `double`.

Acho que o erro é exatamente na linha que você apontou

```
double ram = Convert.ToInt32(Program.HardwareInfo.RAM());
```

Você está atribuindo um `int` em uma variável `double`