# Paralelismo e Entity Framework

Tags: c#, paralelismo

Estou tendo alguns problemas ao utilizar paralelismo (não tenho muito conhecimento nessa área) com C# e Entity Framework.

O meu cenário é o seguinte, estou utilizando uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC e dentro dela tenho uma lista de objetos que faço várias validações. Como são muitos (mais de 45 mil em média) se eu ficar esperando em uma única thread, a demora é grande.

Para isso eu pensei em trabalhar com paralelismo, só que acabei tendo alguns problemas como o dbcontext que tive de instanciar para cada thread para poder funcionar em múltiplas threads.

Estou utilizando o Parallel.ForEach(lista, x => MetodoDeValidacao(x).Wait()); para realizar as validações assíncronamente.

Abaixo meu método de validação.

```
public Task MetodoDeValidacao(IEnumerable<Lista> lista) {
     return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
     {
       if (!_service.fazAlgumaCoisa(lista))
          ModelState.AddModelError("Model", "Você não fez alguma coisa");
     }
}
```

Minha dúvida é : Essa é a melhor forma de fazer validações em paralelo? Vocês tem algum artigo para recomendar?

Comment: Isto vai operar no banco de dados? Dê uma lida nisto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101

Comment: Show de bola @bigown!

Answer (score 4):

> Minha dúvida é : Essa é a melhor forma de fazer validações em paralelo?

De jeito algum. Esta é uma das piores, eu diria.

Você está criando aí o [problema do contexto destacado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+contexto+destacado). Este código jamais irá funcionar.

Em primeiro lugar, um contexto não é *thread-safe*. Você precisa invocar o `lock()` nele antes de tentar validar.

Em segundo lugar, não se encapsula um contexto dentro de um serviço e o instancia múltiplas vezes. A coleção como um todo precisa ser observável. Portanto é um contexto apenas para N validações.

Ao invés de usar serviço, use uma classe estática, passando por referência o contexto e travando o contexto numa região crítica ao validar.

Comment: Valeu Cigano, é que o meu cenário hoje tá bem complicado... recebo uma planilha excel e através dela faço 3 validações para cada linha, que para realizá-las preciso de dados do banco (geralmente são 45.000  linhas, o que demora demais). Minha ideia foi realizá-las em paralelo, para que não fiquem esperando as outras terminarem.

Comment: Você pode continuar nesta abordagem, só que não pode abrir um contexto por etapa de validação. Passar o contexto por referência para uma função ou método de validação é o caminho.

Comment: OK! Obrigado! Vou fazer os testes de desempenho para ver no que vai dar =)