# Concorrência e compartilhamento de memória entre Threads

Tags: java, thread, memória, multithreading

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
class Objt
{
    public List<t> list_t1;
    public List<t> list_t2;

    public Objt() 
    {
        // faz inicializações
    }

    public void handleLists(List<t> list)
    {
        for(t e: list)
        {
           ... // manipula elementos da lista
        {
    }
}
```

**Problema:** Tenho liberdade para manipular as duas listas ao mesmo tempo no meu problema, inclusive essa é a intenção. Nesse código acima, só uma thread pode entrar nessa linha de código desse objeto por vez para manipular uma lista, a outra ficaria aguardando para manipular outra lista.

**Pergunta:** Eu poderia bem duplicar esse método `handleLists()` e colocá-los com nome `handleList1()` e `handleList2()` e alocá-los cada um para uma *thread*, porém é meio que gambiarra isso, ou não? Há uma solução mais elegante? Um **Pattern**?

O que eu quero entender agora, visto os comentários, é se eu posso utilizar o mesmo método `handleLists()` nas duas *threads* só passando listas diferentes para cada *thread* e eles executarão em paralelo.

Obs: Tinha colocado `list_t1` e `list_t2` só pra ilustrar um possível uso.

Comment: A pergunta não deixa claro o que deseja de fato, qual é a situação específica, mas se entendi bem o que está escrito, o `synchronized` parece desnecessário. Porque precisaria criar outro método para fazer a mesma coisa? Crie cada *thread* chamando o mesmo método passando cada lista em uma *thread*.

Comment: Cara, a situação é essa apresentada, não tenho muito a acrescentar. Eu preciso manipular as listas de um mesmo objeto em "paralelo". O ``synchronized``  está ali supondo que eu implementasse o caso de duas threads usando o mesmo método daquele objeto cada uma passando uma lista. Com a solução que você falou aí que vai dar problema, as threads mudarão a referência à variável ``list`` do método toda hora, e assim vou obter um resultado completamente indesejável, porque eu chamo o mesmo método do mesmo objeto toda vez.

Comment: Se são duas listas diferentes não tem porque uma interferir na outra. Acho que ainda não entendeu como as *threads* funcionam. Ou então está relatando um problema completamente diferente do que realmente quer e deseja mexer na mesma lista em duas *threads*. Mas não é o que está escrito. E se for também, provavelmente não terá o ganho que está esperando. Leia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101. E leia a resposta do Piovesan que confirma isto. Ele considerou que o código vai usar as duas listas no método, eu acho que não (acho porque o código não foi mostrado, então tem o que acrescentar).

Comment: Adicionei mais detalhes após avaliar algumas coisas aqui cara!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na minha experiência não é comum você ter duas listas independentes necessitando de acesso sincronizado em um objeto. Pode ser indício de uma violação do Princípio de Responsabilidade Única. Mas isso é uma questão de design e não vem ao caso.

Tenha em mente que o acesso sincronizado a um trecho de código depende de um "token", isto é, um objeto do qual só existe uma instância, de forma que quem tiver ele num determinado momento pode executar a ação desejada, caso contrário terá que esperar o dono do *token* liberá-lo para que ele possa adquirir esse *token* e efetuar a ação. Com a diferença que o termo usado não é "token" e sim "lock" (ou semáforo, monitor, etc). O que quero dizer é que a função dele é ser um *token*. É disso que se trata o acesso sincronizado: o *thread* que possui o *lock* pode entrar no trecho de código sincronizado e executá-lo (e fazer operações sobre as suas listas, por exemplo).

Qualquer objeto pode ser um "lock". Quando um método é `synchronized`, o *lock* é o próprio objeto que contém aquele método. No caso do seu exemplo, se você tiver um código assim...

```
Objt bijeto = new Objt();
bijeto.handleLists(list);
```

...o objeto `bijeto` será o lock para o método sincronizado `handleLists()`.

A escolha do *lock* (ou dos *locks*) mais apropriado(s) para o seu caso vai depender da sua intenção. Quando um *thread* tem acesso a `list_t1`, você quer que ele também tenha acesso a `list_t2`? Nesse caso, pode usar um lock só para as duas listas. Esse *lock* pode ser o próprio objeto `Objt`, ou então um outro objeto que você define como atributo de `Objt`.

Ou quando um *thread* tem acesso a `list_t1`, você NÃO quer que ele tenha acesso a `list_t2`? Nesse caso precisará de dois *locks* diferentes. As próprias listas, se forem não-nulas e declaradas como `final`, podem ser usadas como *locks* para acesso a si mesmas. Ou então você pode criar dois atributos `lock_t1` e `lock_t2`.

Importante notar que os dois trechos de código abaixo são equivalentes:

Trecho 1:

```
public class Objt {

    public synchronized handleList() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Trecho 2:

```
public class Objt {

    public handleList() {
        synchronized(this) { // "this" é referência para o próprio
            ...              // objeto de classe Objt
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Edição:**

Você esclareceu que quer ter um método que recebe como parâmetro uma lista e faz alterações nela. Um *thread* irá chamar esse método passando uma lista `list_t1` como parâmetro e outro *thread* irá chamar esse método passando outra lista `list_t2` como parâmetro.

Nesse caso SE esse for o único ponto em que as listas são modificadas, o paralelismo funcionará sem problemas e não haverá necessidade de declarar o método `synchronized`, como o @Maniero falou na resposta dele, que responde perfeitamente a pergunta. Vai funcionar porque o método não está fazendo nenhuma alteração em estado compartilhado, somente no estado dos parâmetros passados a ele, que no caso são independentes um do outro.

Mas evite declarar as listas na classe que contém esse mesmo método, isso só cria confusão (pois se elas são atributos de uma classe não seria necessário passá-las como parâmetro para métodos dessa mesma classe).

Ou então pare de declarar tudo como `public` e procure aprender a usar os modificadores de acesso do Java para refletirem corretamente suas intenções no código.

Se quiser deixar o código mais elegante, dê mais detalhes sobre o que deseja fazer e inclua mais código na pergunta, inclusive dos *threads* que chamam o tal método, que mostramos a você como ele pode ficar.

Comment: Num era bem isso que eu queria cara, talvez a minha pergunta estava com pouco detalhes, dê uma olhada nela agora cara!

Comment: Complementei a resposta.

Comment: Isso aí cara, o @bigown falou dessa parte agora. Eu queria entender era se o paralelismo ia funcionar ou ia dar problema nas referências das listas, mas então tá respondido. Acerca de detalhes do código, desconsidere, escrevi esse breve código aqui só pra ilustrar as listas e o método para utilizá-las.

Answer (score 5):

A resposta do Piovezan dá ótima explicação do problema que está tendo na utilização do método, então vou só complementar com a parte que eu entendi diferente na pergunta (que diga-se de passagem, não é muito clara nesse ponto).

Se o método receberá simultaneamente listas diferentes, no caso uma chamada em uma *thread* receberá `list_t1` e a outra chamada em outra *thread* receberá `list_t2` e o método não manipulará o parâmetro `list` que conterá ou uma ou a outra lista em cada chamada, eles não se confundirão, são chamadas completamente isoladas e não haverá problemas de concorrência. Sendo assim, não só não há problemas em chamar este método em mais de um *thread* simultaneamente, alcançando paralelismo, como nem precisará marcá-lo como `synchronized`. Nem mesmo precisará sincronizar nada internamente, o que pode até acabar com o paralelismo dependendo de como for usado ([já falei disto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101)).

Claro que pode não ser bem isso dependendo do conteúdo do método, que não foi postado.

Como adendo, criar outro método não ajudará em nada. Na verdade, dependendo do que fizer, pode até trazer mais problemas.

Comment: "e o método ``no`` manipulará..." esse "no" é o que? Mas parece que é isso que eu queria saber então cara, queria saber se eles executam isoladamente ou não, mesmo que cada thread manipule sua lista! Então valeu.

Comment: É "não", editado. Obrigado.

Comment: Só uma pergunta cara: O @Piovezan deu exemplo de dois usos do ``synchronized`` e eu até já sabia disso, porém fiquei com uma dúvida. Se uma thread entra em um bloco sincronizado (seja um método ou bloco mesmo) de um objeto, mas outra thread estava utilizando outro método desse mesmo objeto isoladamente, com outros serviços, essa thread pára porque a outra thread entrou no bloco sincronizado, ou seja, utilizou o ``lock``/``monitor``/``token`` desse objeto ou não?

Comment: Se entendi o que está dizendo, sim, uma bloqueia a outra.