# Qual a diferença entre escalonamento vertical e horizontal?

Tags: banco-de-dados, servidor, terminologia, cloud, escalabilidade

Recentemente tenho visto alguns assuntos sobre *cloud*, *BD's*, etc. Em alguns desses assuntos vejo bastante o termo **escalonamento**. Diante desse tema tenho as seguintes dúvidas:

- Qual a diferença entre escalonamento vertical e horizontal?
- Existem outros tipos de escalonamento?

Comment: Veja: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707879/difference-between-scaling-horizontally-and-vertically-for-databases

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## *Scaling up*

O **escalonamento vertical** é botar mais capacidade de memória (principal e/ou de massa) e processamento. Ou seja, é comprar um hardware mais poderoso para dar conta do recado.

Em alguns casos basta criar mais processos/*threads* que está fazendo o *scaling up*, desde que o hardware já suporte esse aumento. Há casos que separar o banco de dados em vários dispositivos de armazenamento já seja uma escala vertical, novamente é escalar na mesma máquina.

O investimento é basicamente em hardware. Comprando mais processador. memória e armazenamento já tem uma capacidade aumentada.

Em alguns casos é mais questão de fazer uma simples configuração para alcançar o que o hardware único já suporta.

Também pode ser otimizar a aplicação para que ela desempenhe melhor e atenda mais do que fazia antes.

## *Scaling out*

O **escalonamento horizontal** é colocar mais computadores para dar conta do recado. Claro que eles adicionam mais capacidade de processamento e memória também, na soma total.

É muito mais complexo fazer um escalonamento horizontal tanto do ponto de vista de gerenciamento quanto do ponto de vista de programação, ainda que existam ferramentas para facilitar. Não é só colocar os computadores, eles precisam "se falar" de forma consistente e adequada. Na verdade isso é considerado o problemas mais difícil de resolver na computação.

Por incrível que pareça pode ser mais barato que o vertical, pelo menos no custo da aquisição da infraestrutura já que é possível adquirir hardware mais simples e mais comum que costuma ser mais barato pela escala de produção. Claro que o custo de gerenciamento e desenvolvimento pode mudar o custo total.

Fora os casos que o vertical não comportaria a necessidade, afinal essa estratégia tem um limite que em tese o horizontal não tem, o horizontal tem a vantagem de ser mais tolerante a falhas, ou pelo menos ser mais fácil ter a operação de volta em caso de alguma falha.

## Diferenças

Qualquer banco de dados minimamente estruturado pode fazer os dois tipos de escalonamento. O vertical não precisa nenhuma propriedade específica a não ser no caso de separar dados em vários dispositivos de armazenamento ou permitir várias linhas de processamento, por isso não é simples fazer em certas modelagens. O horizontal precisa de mecanismos que permitam e, se possível, facilitem o escalonamento horizontal. Não importa se ele é do tipo não relacional ou não, se usa SQL ou não.

Desconheço outros tipos, nem sei se é possível ter. Existem variações dessas formas, principalmente no horizontal existem muitas estratégias e técnicas. Também pode fazer um escalonamento híbrido.

São raras as aplicações que precisam de escala horizontal. Pelo menos no sentido de escala mesmo. Pode ser útil fazê-lo pela confiabilidade maior de ter mais de um nó atendendo as requisições, mas não que precise de mais recursos. O grosso da necessidade vem de aplicações web de alta demanda ou processamentos muito específicos.

Pode não parecer a mesma coisa mas tem [uma pergunta que está relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101), mostrando que escalar qualquer coisa horizontalmente pode parecer a solução, mas nem sempre resolve ou compensa a dificuldade que é inerente dela.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Valeu pela explicação clara @bigown

Answer (score 8):

Escalonamento *Horizontal*  você adiciona mais máquinas em seu pool de recursos enquanto escalonamento *Vertical* significa que você adiciona mais poder *(CPU, RAM)* para uma máquina existente.

Em um banco de dados Horizontal é muitas vezes baseada no particionamento dos dados, ou seja, cada nó contém apenas parte dos dados.

No banco de dados Vertical os dados residem em um único nó e o dimensionamento é feito através de multi-core, ou seja, espalha a carga entre o CPU e a memória RAM.

No escalonamento horizontal  muitas vezes é mais fácil de redimensionar dinamicamente adicionando mais máquinas, já na Vertical é muitas vezes limitada à capacidade de uma única máquina escalonar,além de que a capacidade muitas vezes envolve o tempo de inatividade e vem com um limite superior.

**Exemplo escalonamento horizontal:** *Cassandra, MongoDB..*

**Exemplo escalonamento vertical** *MySQL - Amazon RDS (A versão nuvem de MySQL)*. Ele fornece uma maneira fácil de escalar verticalmente, passando de pequenos para máquinas maiores. Este processo envolve muitas vezes o tempo de inatividade.

*In-Memory Dados Grids como GigaSpaces XAP , Coerência etc ..* são frequentemente otimizado tanto para escalonamento horizontal e vertical, simplesmente porque não é obrigado a disco. Horizontal através de particionamento e vertical através de apoio multi-core.

[FONTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707879/difference-between-scaling-horizontally-and-vertically-for-databases)

Answer (score 5):

Só para contextualização, o que gera a necessidade de fazer algum tipo de escalonamento é que o crescimento do acesso à internet fez com que as grandes redes sociais, sistemas de buscas, entre outros, recebessem uma grande quantidade de dados. Devido a esse crescimento, uma grande quantidade de dados é gerada e esses dados são valiosos, visto que são utilizados como fonte de informação para tomada de decisões estratégicas e mineração de dados.

No **escalonamento horizontal**, vários computadores ou máquinas virtuais rodam o mesmo aplicativo e a carga de usuários é distribuída entre eles. Deste modo, em caso de atualizações, não é necessário deixar todo o sistema fora do ar, mas apenas uma máquina por vez. Já no **escalonamento vertical**, ao invés de designar múltiplas máquinas para essa função, uma única máquina é utilizada e, quando preciso, investe-se em seu melhoramento, por exemplo, investir em um HD com maior capacidade ou um processador e uma conexão mais rápida para suportar o alto número de acessos simultâneos. Isso acontece devido à natureza centralizada dos bancos relacionais, o que torna necessário que eles estejam em uma única máquina. O problema desse tipo de escalonamento é a relação custo-benefício, pois me percebendo um bom desempenho no início, o investimento em hardware gera pouca melhora de performance do sistema. Para amenizar esses problemas existem algumas técnicas que possibilitam estender/prolongar o uso de bancos de dados relacionais, como *[sharding](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(arquitetura_de_banco_de_dados))*, [desnormalização](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desnormaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o) e cache distribuído. Porém, essas técnicas apenas tentam compensar as limitações destes bancos com escalonamento horizontal.

Referência:

- [Bancos de Dados NoSQL x SGBDs Relacionais:Análise Comparativa](http://www.infobrasil.inf.br/userfiles/27-05-S4-1-68840-Bancos%20de%20Dados%20NoSQL.pdf)
- [Por dentro do banco de dados](http://www.devmedia.com.br/por-dentro-do-banco-de-dados-nosql-couchbase/34408)