# Qual a diferença entre escalabilidade e elasticidade?

Tags: terminologia, escalabilidade

Até então o meu entendimento entre os termos é um tanto quanto confuso:

- **Escalabidade:** aumentar a capacidade do sistema conforme o aumento da demanda;
- **Elasticidade:** aumentar ou diminuir a capacidade do sistema conforme a demanda;

Mas dessa forma, tenho os seguintes problemas:

- Todo sistema elástico também é escalável, causando redundância;
- Num sistema escalável não é possível remover recursos, então acaba sendo ruim em algum momento no futuro, quando não tiver tanta demanda;

Qual seria a definição mais clara que permita separar melhor os termos?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Não é redundante porque o escalável não precisa ser elástico. Não poder remover recursos não é uma característica intrínseca do escalável, até pode sim, e mesmo se não puder ou não for feito, isto não necessariamente é um problema. Ser escalável não se preocupa com essas coisas.

O problema é a definição do termo escalabilidade. Ele é sobre a capacidade de atender demandas maiores, não determina como, não impõe requisitos gerais. Uma necessidade de escala pode impor requisitos específicos.

Alias, as pessoas entendem escalabilidade como a capacidade de servidores atenderem mais demanda. O termo é muito mais amplo que isso e pode ser aplicado em outros contextos. Podemos estar falando de [escalabilidade de software](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90297/101).

A forma de escalar não é definida. Uma dessas formas pode ser a elasticidade, pode ser que o que está escalando nem tem sentido ter elasticidade.

Em servidores podemos [escalar vertical ou horizontalmente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/160142/101).

A **facilidade e velocidade de fazer essa mudança de escala, tanto para aumentar, quanto para diminuir determinará se o sistema é elástico**. Algo elástico tende a usar apenas os recursos necessários. A necessidade e a mudança de escala pode ser até mesmo gerenciada por software. Em geral algo é elástico se pode ser feito automaticamente.

A nuvem é um mecanismo e uma forma de comercialização com objetivo de oferecer a elasticidade. Ou deveria ser, na prática em geral ficou melhor, para os fornecedores, não dar tanta elasticidade assim, obtendo melhor faturamento e mais lucro ainda porque a pessoa pode pagar por algo que não usa.

O que muita gente não percebe é que ser elástico não significa gastar menos. É muito comum gastar mais, porque tem um preço mais alto. Muito menos ser elástico é a melhor solução. Se fosse melhor e mais barato todo mundo usava assim.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).