# O que é sharding?

Tags: banco-de-dados, terminologia, arquitetura-de-software

Qual é a utilidade do *sharding*? Por que é tão importante para bancos de dados e/ou programação?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## TL; DR

É uma forma de distribuir dados em vários servidores.

## Detalhando

*Sharding* é só um nome pomposo para [particionamento de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/160142/101). Especialmente quando esse particionamento é horizontal, ou seja, se distribui por máquinas diferentes.

Em geral aplicações com um volume muito grande de dados precisam ser particionadas para dar conta do recado, precisa haver distribuição da carga de trabalho ou mesmo de armazenamento.

Em alguns casos pode ser na mesma máquina, usando dispositivos de armazenamento distintos, mas é mais raro porque existem outras soluções quando a necessidade é apenas esta.

Isso ocorre principalmente com bancos de dados. E por isso alguns deles já possuem mecanismo pronto para fazer o tal *sharding*, em alguns casos de forma transparente para o usuário (programador).

Particionar é um dos itens do [teorema CAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem). Você pode ter 2 deles entre **consistência**, **disponibilidade** e **particionamento**, escolha um modelo que permita os dois que sejam mais adequados para você, mas não é possível escolher os 3.

Como a maioria dos problemas não precisam do *sharding* você pode escolher o que costuma ser mais interessante para a maioria das aplicações: a consistência e a disponibilidade. Quando o particionamento for mais importante, aí tem que escolher um desses dois para abrir mão. Cada aplicação ficará melhor com um conjunto.

Minha experiência mostra que quase tudo ficar melhor, só entre os dois, quando abre mão da disponibilidade, até porque, se bem-feito, ela é muito curta e só atrasa um pouco, mas nada crítico.

Mas existem casos que a consistência é menos importante mesmo. Por alguma razão as pessoas estão escolhendo abrir mão dela, até quando não precisa do particionamento. Ok, se ela realmente não é necessária, mas escolhem onde ela é, até porque escolhem a ferramenta errada para a tarefa que não dá a consistência, então a pessoa não escolhe o modelo, o modelo foi escolhido pelo fornecedor da ferramenta com marketing eficiente.

É possível fazer *sharding* em qualquer modelo, mas terá que abrir mão de um dos dois outros itens, e algumas ferramentas possuem mais facilidade para um ou outro.

[A Wikipedia define o termo muito para bancos de dados relacionais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture)). Não me parece que ele seja restrito só a eles. Já vi o termo sendo usado em outros contextos, mas pode ser uso errado. Não achei nada que confirmasse que só é *sharding* quando está tratando de relacionais.

Eu vi ele sendo [usado até como um padrão de arquitetura](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/sharding?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

O artigo demonstra que não é fácil fazer o particionamento em SGDBRs.

Ali explica que *sharding* é mais que o particionamento simples. O artigo não é tão bom, mas dá a entender que ele faz um particionamento com consistência, abrindo mão da disponibilidade, pelo menos em alguns cenários.

Uma definição interessante que eu achei é que o *sharding* é uma forma oposta, em certo sentido, da [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101). Esta última é definida como quebrar a informação em colunas separadas. Já o *sharding* seria a quebra das linhas. Então você terá uma tabela com os produtos de um grupo, outra tabela com produtos de outro grupo, e assim vai. É uma explicação simples, sem entrar no mérito de todo mecanismo.

Note que se o problema for só a carga de leitura de dados uma replicação completa pode ser muito mais fácil, mas nem sempre aplicável com adequação.

Não use sem necessidade extrema. Em muitos casos o programador não precisa lidar com isso, mesmo que a aplicação dependa dele. O DBA pode fazer acontecer de forma transparente na maioria dos casos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).