# O que vem a ser ThreadPool?

Tags: java, thread, terminologia, multithreading

Estou estudando `Threads` em `Java`, e me deparei com o seguinte código:

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    threadPool.submit(new CriarClientes(NOMES[i]));

    threadPool.shutdown();

    while (!threadPool.isTerminated()) {
    }

    ClienteRepository.instance().list();
```

Eu gostaria de saber o que é o `ThreadPool`, e por que se passa um `inteiro` para o construtor. Ouvi que ele cria o número de `Threads` que passa para o `construtor` porém não entendi muito bem onde aplicar na prática.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

É um conjunto de *threads* pré-instanciadas prontas para uso. Elas não costumam ser liberadas, e ficam lá disponíveis (em *idle*) para reciclagem. Na verdade o processo de criação e destruição é um pouco mais complicado que isto e dependente de implementação, mas o básico é isso. Algumas serão destruídas se tiver excesso.

Criar uma *thread* custa um pouco caro. Manter controle de todas ativas não é uma tarefa tão simples. Ter um objeto que gerencie isso ajuda muito já que ele foi feito por quem entende bem do assunto, e com ele viabiliza usar *threads* de execução mais curta, já que o custo é minimizado por não ter que ficar criando e destruindo várias *threads*.

Em alguns casos é possível criar uma fila de execução.

## Exemplo específico

De fato o [`newFixedThreadPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) cria um *pool* com 10 *threads* e não passará disto, se passar, entra em fila.

A forma como está usando não é um problema, mas há pouco ou nenhum ganho em relação ao uso normal de *threads*. Talvez fique mais organizado, mas o desempenho não será melhorado.

## Conclusão

O padrão de projeto de *pool* é muito usado em vários casos avançados de programação para reaproveitar objetos que podem ser reciclados.

[Mais informações na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool).

Isso pode ajudar: [É sempre garantido que uma aplicação com múltiplas threads rode mais rápido que usando uma única thread?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101)

Se tiver dúvidas específicas, manda pra gente.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado, então a maneira que está sendo utilizada é meramente para fins didáticos, quero aprofundar mais no assunto, vou tentar implementar.

Answer (score 13):

## Executor

A pergunta deveria ser sobre o `ExecutorService` ou apenas `Executor`. Tais APIs são uma abstração ao controle manual de threads para execução de um conjunto de operações assíncronas.

Portanto, o primeiro objetivo aqui é tornar o desenvolvimento assíncrono mais amigável e menos propenso a erros, sem necessidade de sincronização manual.

## Thread pool

Um tipo específico de `Executor` é aquele que possui um *thread pool* (`ThreadPoolExecutor`).

Um *thread pool* que nada mais é do que um tipo de reservatório de *threads*, que ficam à espera de um trabalho a fazer. Lembrando que uma *thread* em Java é representada por uma instância da classe `Thread`.

## Criando um executor com *pool* de tamanho fixo

No seu exemplo, você usou o método estático `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)` - um *factory method* - para criar uma instância da classe `ThreadPoolExecutor`, com um comportamento específico.

Basicamente:

- O *pool* começa vazio.
- Cada tarefa submetida, usando o `submit()`, cria uma nova thread no *pool* para executar a tarefa, até o limite de 10 threads.
- Após atingido o limite de 10 threads no pool, cada nova tarefa submetida vai ser executada por uma thread existente, se houver alguma livre, caso contrário a tarefa entra numa fila, que é consumida assim que alguma outra tarefa acabar.

Como já mencionei, existem diferentes tipos de `Executor`s para diferentes cenários. Além disso, usando parâmetros diferentes para instanciar um `ThreadPoolExecutor`, você pode adicionar diferentes limites superior no número de threads, por exemplo, um *pool* que fica tem um mínimo de 10 threads, mas pode chegar a 20 se houverem muitas tarefas na fila.

## Considerações sobre desempenho

Usar um `Executor` com um *thread pool* potencialmente melhora o desempenho se houver uma quantidade razoável de tarefas assíncronas a serem executadas.

A principal razão é referente ao melhor uso das CPUs disponíveis. Por exemplo, criar 1000 threads e executá-las ao mesmo tempo numa CPU com 8 processadores, irá potencialmente gerar muita sobrecarga para o algoritmo de agendamento, consumir muita memória de uma só vez e, se houver acesso sincronizado a um objeto compartilhado, gerará enorme contenção e várias threads ficarão bloqueadas ao mesmo tempo. Neste cenário, geralmente é mais eficiente permitir um número limitado de tarefas simultâneas. O limite ótimo de threads é totalmente dependente do ambiente e só pode ser determinado através de experimentos.

Outra razão está relacionada à criação das threads. Se o número de tarefas for grande e a duração de cada uma for curta, então o reuso de threads pode ajudar um pouco. Entretanto, este não é um grande argumento, porque ainda existe *overhead* para gerenciamento das *threads* no pool e alguns tipos de sincronização que são necessários.

Por outro lado, antes de dividir uma tarefa grande em outras pequenas, é sempre preciso considerar se existe um real benefício nisso, se cada tarefa é realmente individual.

No seu exemplo, se a criação dos clientes for, por exemplo, um acesso a um serviço remoto cujo gargalo está no tempo de resposta e não na quantidade de dados, realmente faz sentido paralelizar 10 requisições. Agora suponha que o gargalo esteja na rede, neste caso paralelizar 10 requisições vai aumentar o tempo total de transferência, aumentar a possibilidade de um *timeout* e as chances de alguma falha na rede.

Outro erro comum é paralelizar o acesso a um banco de dados. Suponha que no exemplo são abertas 10 conexões paralelas, cada uma inserindo um registro no banco. Além de gastar recursos desnecessários, diminuindo a capacidade total do servidor em número de usuários, isto provavelmente não é mais rápido do que fazer uma inserção em massa dos dados. As razões envolvem um overhead da abertura das conexões e o fato de que em operações de escrita o banco ainda precisa sincronizar as gravações.

## Outros usos

O uso de `Executor`s em geral é recomendado em Java pelas razões citadas no início, a saber:

- Facilita e agiliza o desenvolvimento, pois trata-se de uma API mais simples em relação à sincronização manual de *threads*.
- Evita erros, pois abstrai muitos dos conceitos difíceis de concorrência.

Portanto, mesmo quando a performance seja um pouco prejudicada, a sanidade dos programadores é razão suficiente para o uso da API.

## Modo correto de finalizar as tarefas

O exemplo da pergunta utiliza uma técnica muito ruim para aguardar a finalização das tarefas submetidas.

O laço `while (!threadPool.isTerminated()) { }` irá executar continuamente, ocupando uma CPU para verificar o término das tarefas.

Utilizar um mecanismo de bloqueio da thread para aguardar a operação terminar irá liberar a thread atual para executar outras coisas mais importantes enquanto o código não faz nada de útil. Numa CPU com 4 cores livres, isto pode representar uma diferença de 25% na eficiência do programa.

Vamos a um exemplo melhorado:

```
//nome apropriado para a variável
final ExecutorService criarClientesExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

//sempre use chaves, é uma boa prática para não errar na leitura do código
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    criarClientesExecutor.submit(new CriarClientes(NOMES[i]));
}

criarClientesExecutor.shutdown();

//aguarda a conclusão sem ocupar o processador
criarClientesExecutor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

ClienteRepository.instance().list();
```

Cuidado com alguns métodos como `shutdownNow()` e `tryTerminate()`, pois eles irão ativar a flag de interrupção das threads. Isso significa que se uma *threads* está bloqueada por um *lock* ou fazendo alguma operação no disco, no banco de dados, na rede, uma exceção será lançada e a operação não será finalizada.

## Coletando resultados individualmente

No exemplo acima, o *executor*  e suas *threads* são recriados a cada execução do trecho. Entretanto, outro cenário comum é manter um *executor* compartilhado, e os lugares que submetem uma tarefa geralmente querem o resultado individual dela.

Neste caso, a basta usar o retorno de um dos métodos `submit()` que é um `Future`. Exemplo:

```
//submete a tarefa
final Future<Integer> future = executor.submit(task);

//executa algo em paralelo ...

//coleta o resultado aqui - ou aguarda se ainda não houver acabado
Integer resultado = future.get();
```

Answer (score 2):

`ThreadPool` seria uma coleção de threads organizados em uma fila e que executam uma lista de tarefas. A ideia é te ajudar a evitar de criar ou destruir mais threads do que seria realmente necessário. Assim que uma tarefa é concluida, a thread ativa solicita outra tarefa.

Quando você define, no método `newFixedThreadPool`, o inteiro 10, você está definindo uma lista de no máximo 10 threads ativas. Se mais de 10 threads forem submetidas, elas serão mantidas em fila até que outras threads sejam encerradas.