# Conversão de for aninhado para threads

Tags: c#, .net, thread, multithreading, for

Tenho o seguinte `for` aninhado que percorre toda a extensão de uma imagem *bitmap* em C#. Gostaria de rodar o segundo for com *threads* para que fosse executado paralelamente.

```
Bitmap alterado = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height);

//Convertendo para tons de Cinza
for (int i = 0; i < original.Width; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < original.Height; j++)
    {
        Color corOriginal = original.GetPixel(i, j);
        int escalaCinza = (int)((corOriginal.R * 0.3) + (corOriginal.G * 0.49) + (corOriginal.B * 0.11));
        Color CorEmEscalaDeCinza = Color.FromArgb(escalaCinza, escalaCinza, escalaCinza);
        alterado.SetPixel(i, j, CorEmEscalaDeCinza);
    }
}

return alterado;
```

Como posso fazer ?

Comment: Mas o segundo for não depende do primeiro?

Comment: Gostaria que quando acabasse o segundo for, que ele incrementasse o primeiro.

Comment: E qual o sentido do paralelismo daí?

Comment: Rodaria apenas o for do j em paralelo.

Comment: Mas por quê? Se o primeiro `for` vai ter que esperar o segundo acabar?

Comment: E o que quer fazer? isso é o que importa. Na verdade tem grande chance de não servir pra nada, ou até prejudicar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101

Comment: Se tiver uma forma de rodar o for do i paralelamente sem esperar os for dos j terminarem, é melhor

Comment: O objetivo é transformar a imagem colorida em preto e branco. Já tenho o algoritmo que funciona de forma sequencial. gostaria de converte-lo para paralelo

Comment: Se for uma imagem pequena não compensa, se forem várias imagens, é melhor paralelizar as imagens e não o algoritmo individual, se for uma grande, mas muito grande mesmo, o ganho será pequeno, se tiver. E se for possível, nem tudo dá para paralelizar. Por isso que precisa ver o que deseja fazer.

Comment: É um exercício da faculdade. Preciso fazer de forma serial e paralela e comparar os dois, pra ver se compensa ou não fazer de forma paralela. Percebi que pra imagens pequenas, o algoritmo sequencial foi rápido, para imagens maiores (4K de resolução) demorou 23 segundos. Gostaria do algoritmo paralelo para poder comparar.

Comment: @RaphaelPradodeOliveira mas então os `for` são independentes entre eles?

Comment: São. Cada pixel da imagem q eu percorro, é independente um do outro.

Comment: Cara, como é independente se você usa o `i` dentro do segundo for?

Comment: A resposta ajudou chegar na solução? Acha que pode aceitá-la?

Answer (score 1):

Tenta isto:

```
Parallel.For(0, original.Height, j => {
    for (int i = 0; i < original.Width; i++) {
        Color corOriginal = original.GetPixel(i, j);
        int escalaCinza = (int)((corOriginal.R * 0.3) + (corOriginal.G * 0.49) + (corOriginal.B * 0.11));
        Color CorEmEscalaDeCinza = Color.FromArgb(escalaCinza, escalaCinza, escalaCinza);
        alterado.SetPixel(i, j, CorEmEscalaDeCinza);
    }
});
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Other/ParallelFor.cs).

Tenha em mente que usar em paralelo o mesmo algoritmo que é usado para sequencial nem sempre é a melhor solução. Está comparando coisas erradas. Em paralelo deveria fazer de outra forma, aí talvez tenha ganho. Fora isto, leia o que eu comentei acima e o *link* que forneci lá.

Leia sobre o [`LockBits`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0#System_Drawing_Bitmap_LockBits_System_Drawing_Rectangle_System_Drawing_Imaging_ImageLockMode_System_Drawing_Imaging_PixelFormat_). Também funcionaria com [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), mas é menos eficiente.

Comment: A seguinte exception é retornada nesse método :
Additional information: O objeto está sendo usado em outro lugar.

Comment: Eu achei que seria uma ajuda. O uso do `LockBits` provavelmente seria mais adequado, acho que esse é outro problema. Se considera uma resposta errada, eu posso apagar.