# For aninhado de forma paralela

Tags: c#, multithreading, for, paralelismo

Estou tentando rodar dois `for` aninhado. O segundo gostaria que fosse de forma paralela. Segue meu código.

```
for (int i = 0; i < original.Width; i++)
    {
        Parallel.For(0, original.Height, j =>
        {
            Color originalColor = original.GetPixel(i, j);
            Color CorEmNegativo = Color.FromArgb(255 - originalColor.R, 255 - originalColor.G, 255 - originalColor.B);
            alterado.SetPixel(i, j, CorEmNegativo);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        });
    }
```

O seguinte erro é retornando pra mim: `O objeto está sendo usado em outro lugar.` Como posso fazer ?

Comment: Qual é linha do erro?

Comment: Acho que não vai rolar... O erro já tá dizendo, o objeto (original) já está sendo usado em outro processo, como vc está rodando o for em paralelo, mais de uma thread está acessando o mesmo objeto simultaneamente, aparentemente existe uma proteção contra isso.

Comment: Provavelmente o problema deve ser com a variável alterado. Você pode tentar usar isso: `lock(alterado) { alterado.SetPixel(i, j, CorEmNegativo); }`

Comment: Ocorreu o mesmo erro @RicardoPontual

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/169116/101

Comment: Mas deu erro em qual linha???

Comment: Na linha do Parallel.For ...

Comment: ontem eu fiz esse teste dele aí usando Task dentro de um For normal, dava a mesma mensagem de erro, quando tentava executar "original.GetPixel(i, j);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tive que fazer da seguinte maneira, e funcinou:

```
for (int i = 0; i < original.Width; i++)
{
    Parallel.For(0, original.Height, j =>
     {
        lock (alterado)
        {
             Color originalColor = original.GetPixel(i, j);
             Color CorEmNegativo = Color.FromArgb(255 - originalColor.R, 255 - originalColor.G, 255 - originalColor.B);
             alterado.SetPixel(i, j, CorEmNegativo);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: E ficou mais rápido?

Comment: Não. esse lock deixou o dobro do tempo praticamente

Comment: Foi o que eu imaginei. è o que eu falo aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101

Comment: O lock que você implementou para solucionar o problema só dificulta a implementação de dois for aninhados não paralelos, pois para cada ciclo do for interno (teoricamente paralelo) o for exterior tem sua execução bloqueada pelo lock. Logo o resultado prático é exatamente o mesmo (se não mais lento) que o for aninhado convencional.