# Processo em paralelo mais rápido porém duplica número do boleto

Tags: c#, paralelismo

Tenho um processo que precisa percorrer uma lista de 3000 contas a receber, gerar um número de boleto e salvar. Fiz uma abordagem em paralelo que é muito mais rápida, porém duplica o número dos boletos, e uma sequencial, que leva 1 minuto mas não duplica.

O código está simplificado para não ficar extenso, mas é bom próximo ao original.

Abordagem 1 (Esse trecho leva 20 segundos para executar, porém duplica o número dos boletos)

```
 Parallel.ForEach(contasReceber, contaReceber =>
 {
     using (var faturaBLO = new Fatura())
     {
         faturaBLO.SalvarContaReceber(contaReceber);
     }
  });
```

Obs: Nessa abordagem preciso instanciar um objeto de `Fatura` em cada iteração pois essa classe tem uma variável de classe do tipo `DbContext` que não é Thread-Safe. Se instanciar o objeto `faturaBLO` fora do ForEach, dá erro de concorrência(algo do tipo).

Abordagem 2 (leva 60 segundos e gera os números de boleto corretamente)

```
using (var faturaBLO = new Fatura())
{
   foreach (var contaReceber in contasReceber)
   {
      faturaBLO.SalvarContaReceber(contaReceber);
   }
}
```

Dentro da classe `Fatura` é basicamente isso

```
public string ProximoNossoNumero(long codigoConta)
{
            int nossoNumero = 0;

            string stringNossoNumero = ctx.tbConta.Where( c=>c.codigoConta== codigoConta)
                                                  .Select(c => c.ultimoNossoNumero)
                                                  .FirstOrDefault();

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringNossoNumero))
            {
                int.TryParse(stringNossoNumero, out nossoNumero);
            }

            return (nossoNumero + 1).ToString("D8");
 }

 public void AtualizarNossoNumero(long codigoConta, string nossoNumero)
    {
        tbConta conta = ctx.tbConta.FirstOrDefault(c => c.codigoConta== codigoConta);
        if (conta != null)
        {
            conta.ultimoNossoNumero= nossoNumero;
            ctx.Entry(conta).State = EntityState.Modified;
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

   public void SalvarContaReceber(tbContaReceber contaReceber)
   {
      contaReceber.nossoNumero = ProximoNossoNumero(contaReceber.codigoContaBoleto);
      ctx.tbContaReceber.Add(contaReceber);
      ctxt.SaveChanges();

      AtualizarNossoNumero(contaReceber.codigoContaBoleto, contaReceber.nossoNumero);

   }
```

Alguma alternativa para eliminar essa duplicação nos números do boleto no processo paralelo?

Comment: Leia isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101. Não digo que não possa fazer nada pra melhorar, até porque não analisei os detalhes (nem tenho todos eles), mas tá parecendo que este caso feito da maneira correta não vai trazer vantagem significativa em paralelizar.

Comment: Verdade. Nesse caso acho que não vai dar mesmo. A geração dos números tem que ser sequencial mesmo. Vou deixar o paralelismo para a parte de gerar os arquivos PDF do boleto.