# Como funciona o hint Parallel

Tags: sql, oracle, paralelismo

Uma das primeiras coisas que vejo uma galera sugerir pra aumentar a performance de uma `query` no `Oracle` é o uso do hint `Parallel`. Quais os benefícios/riscos que o uso desse hint pode trazer, posso ter problemas com concorrência?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hint parallel divide as instruções internas feita pelo db pela quantidade de processadores / cores até o limite estabelecido por você e permitido na configuração do Oracle. Recomenda-se que essa hint em resultados com agregação - group by (sum(), min(), max(), etc), em queries que será feito full table scan. Os beneficios serão sempre a diminuição do tempo da query, e o principal risco é o consumo excessivo de recursos do servidor.

Answer (score 2):

O Paralelismo, disponibilizado na versão [Oracle Database Enterprise Edition](https://www.oracle.com/br/products/database/enterprise-edition/overview/index.html), oferece a ideia de se quebrar uma tarefa em partes para que, em vez de um único processo fazer todo o trabalho, muitos processos possam executar simultaneamente as partes e no final apresentar um resultado único em menos tempo do que o executado por um único processo.

Quando uma consulta SQL é executada em paralelo, cria-se um processo chamado *Query Coordinator* (QC) e vários outros processos *Queries Slaves*, chamados Pn, Onde n varia de acordo com o número de paralelismo indicado no comando.
Por exemplo, quando utilizamos o *hint* `/*+ parallel (P,4) */`, estamos criando um processo QC e os slaves: P1, P2, P3 e P4.

Temos o funcionamento de uma *parallel query* tomando como ponto de partida a consulta:

```
select /*+ paralel (e, 4) */ from emp order by ename ;
```

Representado pela figura:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O *Query Coordinator* (QC) é responsável por coordenar a execução do *Queries Slaves*, reunir as informações recebidas por cada processo *slave* e apresentar o conjunto de resultados para o usuário que enviou a consulta SQL.
Os *Queries Slaves* são os verdadeiros responsáveis pela coleta dos dados da consulta SQL em si. Quando *Queries Slaves* terminam a leitura dos dados,estes enviam esses dados para o QC através de mensagens de *buffer*.

Essas mensagens têm seu tamanho especificado pelo parâmetro `parallel_execution_message_size` e são trocadas em uma área específica de *buffer*.

O parâmetro `parallel_automatic_tuning define` o lugar deste buffer de mensagens.
Se o parâmetro estiver setado para `TRUE`, o *buffer* será utilizado na *large pool*, se estiver setado para `FALSE` a área de memória utilizada será a *shared pool*. Portanto, é recomendado que se o banco de dados executa muitas consultas paralelas, estudar um tamanho apropriado para esta área de memória e, além disso, configurar valores mínimos para estas áreas de memória.

Isso demonstra que a **utilização de paralelismo em SQLs deve ser alinhada com o DBA e bem testada**, para que os parâmetros de memória sejam configurados de forma coerente.
Outro ponto importante a ser mencionado é que a abertura de vários processos paralelos em um SQL ocasiona lentidão também na própria abertura dos processos.

**Benefícios:**
A execução paralela proporciona melhorias no desempenho mediante a utilização otimizada dos recursos de hardware do servidor, ou seja, podemos utilizar todas as CPUs de um servidor em uma única atividade o que proporcionaria um ganho significativo no processo, por exemplo. Esta mesma distribuição pode ser realizada em um ambiente *clusterizado* (RAC), onde podemos utilizar, se necessário, os recursos de todos os *nodes* para uma única tarefa/processo.

**Riscos** 
Devemos sempre ficar atentos ao consumo dos recursos do servidor como CPU, memória e discos, pois o paralelismo pode saturar completamente uma máquina, ficando então a cargo do DBA equilibrar cuidadosamente o número de pessoas que executam operações paralelas quanto o grau do paralelismo utilizado para que os recursos do servidor não sejam esgotados.

Sobre **Problemas com concorrência**, prefiro não explicar nessa resposta, visto que nessa pergunta "[É sempre garantido que uma aplicação com múltiplas threads rode mais rápido que usando uma única thread?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1946/%C3%89-sempre-garantido-que-uma-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-m%C3%BAltiplas-threads-rode-mais-r%C3%A1pido-que/1957#1957)", a resposta do **Maniero**, explicar a concorrência de uma forma bem interessante.

Recomendação de leitura:
[O que é uma condição de corrida?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/159342/o-que-%C3%A9-uma-condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-corrida)

**Bibliografia:**

GRAF, Anderson. [Execução paralela de instruções SQL: Parallel Query, DML e DDL](http://www.oraclehome.com.br/2012/05/07/execucao-paralela-de-instrucoes-sql-parallel-query-dml-e-ddl/).  Acesso em:  01 agosto 2017.

FIAMENGUI, José Eduardo. [Paralelismo: Mitos e Fatos](https://oradeep.wordpress.com/2011/01/12/paralelismo-mitos-e-fatos/).  Acesso em:  01 agosto 2017.