# Múltiplos usuários em meu servidor NodeJS acessando a mesma variável

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou com um dúvida sobre como um servidor nodejs funciona com múltiplos usuários. Para contextualizar: 
 Digamos que eu crie uma variável no lado do servidor, o valor dessa variável será sobrescrito se uma outra pessoa também acessar a mesma rota na mesma hora ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine que existe apenas um fluxo de execução. Quando chega uma requisição, ela entra nesse fluxo, a máquina virtual Javascript verifica o que tem de ser feito, delega a atividade (consultar dados no banco, por exemplo) e volta a atender novas requisições enquanto este **processamento paralelo** está acontecendo. Quando a atividade termina (já temos os dados retornados pelo banco), ela volta ao fluxo principal para ser devolvida ao requisitante.

Alguns links que podem te ajudar a entender melhor o node.js:

- [O que é Node.js](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KtDwdoxQL4A) (youtube)
- [O que é Node.js](http://www.luiztools.com.br/post/o-que-e-nodejs-e-outras-5-duvidas-fundamentais/)
- [É sempre garantido que uma aplicação com múltiplas threads rode mais rápido que usando uma única thread?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1946/)

Comment: Agora eu entendi muito obrigado . Vou dar uma conferida nestes links! Vlw mesmo