# Javascript WebWorkers

Tags: javascript

Estou estudando um pouco de `webworkers` e criei esse cenário:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<script src="index.js"></script>
<script src="Http.js"></script>

<body>

    <div id="log">
        <button onclick="sayHI()">Say HI</button>
        <output id="result"></output>
    </div>

    <script>

        function sayHI() {
            console.log('oi');
        }

        let options = {
            length: 1000000
        }

        let vetor = [];
        console.time('start');

        for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            let obj = {
                id: Math.random() * 10,
                timestamp: new Date(),
                nome: (Math.random()).toString().split(0, 50)[0],
                sobrenome: (Math.random()).toString().split(0, 100)[0],
                seila: (Math.random()).toString().split(0, 500)[0],
            }

            vetor.push(obj);
        }
        console.timeEnd('start');

        /*
        let worker = new Worker('index.js');
        worker.addEventListener('message', function (e) {

            vetor.push(e.data.obj);
            if ((e.data.length +1 )== options.length) {
                console.timeEnd('start');
            }

        }, false);

        worker.postMessage(options);*/




    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Código do webworker:

```
addEventListener('message', function (e) {

    for (let i = 0; i < e.data.length; i++) {
        let obj = {
            id: Math.random() * 10,
            timestamp: new Date(),
            nome: (Math.random()).toString().split(0, 50)[0],
            sobrenome: (Math.random()).toString().split(0, 100)[0],
            seila: (Math.random()).toString().split(0, 500)[0],
        }

        postMessage({obj: obj, length: i});
    }

});
```

Executando os dois exemplos obtive esses resultados:

- **Sem webworker:** start: `5378ms`
- **Com webworker:** start: `18969ms`

A diferença é muito grande. Pelo fato do worker trabalhar em uma outra thread, imaginei que o desempenho seria similar ou até mesmo melhor. Mas o que percebi é que, por se tratar de uma nova thread, eu posso tranquilamente ficar chamando meu botão "Say HI" que o mesmo vai funcionar, porém o fato de chamar ele 1 ou N vezes interfere no tempo final que o webworker vai levar pra finalizar a tarefa.

É isso mesmo? Ele deveria levar um tempo tão maior pra processar algo?

Comment: Relacionada, talvez duplicata, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1946

Comment: Excelente resposta