# Utilizando Threads em C# pela primeira vez

Tags: c#, thread, multithreading

Estou tentando fazendo o uso de Threads em C# pela primeira vez, sou iniciante no assunto, então desde já desculpe a pergunta se ela for muito básica. Estou utilizando o código abaixo para utilzar tal procedimento:

```
           private Thread thread;

private void btn_ObtemClientes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        thread = new Thread(() =>

        {

            btn_ObtemClientes.Enabled = false;
            btn_ObtemVlrContas.Enabled = true;

            try
            {



                try
                {
                    FbCommand command_ObtemCliente_loja7001 = new FbCommand("SELECT CLIENTES FROM CLIENTES", ConexaoAoBanco_loja7001);

                    ConexaoAoBanco_loja7001.Open();

                    reader = command_ObtemCliente_loja7001.ExecuteReader();


                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            dtGridView_Resultados_Busca_CtasReceber.Rows.Add(reader[0], reader[1], reader[2]);
                        }
                    }

                    reader.Close();
                    ConexaoAoBanco_loja7001.Close();
                }

                catch (Exception exlj7001)
                {

                    dtGridView_Resultados_Busca_CtasReceber.Rows.Clear();
                    MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Erro ao gravar os dados da loja 7001 no Banco Local!\n\n" + exlj7001.Message, "ERRO!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
               });

           thread.Start();

         }

     }
```

Porém ao clicar no botão, o seguinte erro é retornado:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Operação entre threads inválida: controle 'btn_ObtemClientes' acessado de um thread que não é aquele no qual foi criado.'[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso resolver tal erro? Pesquisei sobre o assunto e vi o uso de  **delegates**, e **invoker** como solução, mas não sei como usar e estou meio perdido no assunto sinceramente.

Comment: A melhor dica que posso te dar, é não usar *threads*, este é um mecanismo bruto e tem coisas melhores como `async` e `Task`. Quase ninguém consegue usar `Thread`corretamente. É verdade que também quase ninguém faz concorrência corretamente e o mais comum é a pessoa usar isso para piorar a situação. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101 Mexer com isso é extremamente complicado até para quem é muito experiente. Evite. E vi outros problemas bem mais básicos no código. Esse código trará enormes problemas.

Comment: Precisei usar threading a uns dias atrás eu utilizei o BackgroundWorker é do c# mesmo, é mais facil de implementar e testar visto que ele emit sinais no final de cada etapa! https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Agradeço imensamente o conselho... Após uma pesquisa mais aprofundada no assunto, percebi que os conselhos para o "não uso" são muito maiores do que para uso. Tinha uma visão errada quanto ao uso Thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se tiver mesmo que utilizar *threads*, então faça o seguinte:

```
private Thread thread;

private void btn_ObtemClientes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        btn_ObtemClientes.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            btn_ObtemClientes.Enabled = false;
        }));

        btn_ObtemVlrContas.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            btn_ObtemVlrContas.Enabled = true;
        }));

        try
        {
            try
            {
                FbCommand command_ObtemCliente_loja7001 = new FbCommand("SELECT CLIENTES FROM CLIENTES", ConexaoAoBanco_loja7001);
                ConexaoAoBanco_loja7001.Open();

                reader = command_ObtemCliente_loja7001.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                        {
                            dtGridView_Resultados_Busca_CtasReceber.Rows.Add(reader[0], reader[1], reader[2]);
                        }));
                    }
                }

                reader.Close();
                ConexaoAoBanco_loja7001.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception exlj7001)
            {
                dataGridView1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    dtGridView_Resultados_Busca_CtasReceber.Rows.Clear();
                }));
                MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Erro ao gravar os dados da loja 7001 no Banco Local!\n\n" + exlj7001.Message, "ERRO!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    });

    thread.Start();
}
```

De qualquer forma, a gestão de *threads* é bastante difícil, para além do que o *debug* por vezes pode ser um pesadelo, pelo que é recomendado que se "vire" para outras opções, como disse o [@Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/maniero), `Async` e `Task`.