# Erro no retorno da API ao ser executada paralelamente - C#

Tags: c#, api

Olá,

Estou com dúvidas quanto a solução que eu poderia aplicar para o seguinte problema:

Construí uma API que ao ser chamada faz diversas chamadas em alguns bancos de dados e depois de compor e concatenar os dados ela efetua uma chamada para uma outra API a qual sou cliente, passando como parâmetro os dados que obtive no início do processo. O problema é que a minha API será chamada por diversos usuários e isso faz com que ela se perca, isto é antes de concluir a primeira chamada ela já esta manipulando dados da segunda trazendo resultados errados.

Perguntas:

1) Há como travar o método inicial da API para que só inicie uma nova execução se concluir a execução em andamento?

2) Ou então há como ela rodar em paralelo com outras chamadas dela mesma recebendo parâmetros diferentes?

Segue um exemplo resumido dos métodos que estou tentando rodar de maneira paralela ou sequencial.

```
    public string ChamadaInicialDaAPI(string paramInic)
    {
        string retApi = IniciaProcessoApi(paramInic);
        return retApi;
    }

    private string IniciaProcessoApi(string paramInic)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            string strPesq1 = “”;
            string retApiExt = “”;

            DAL.ProcessaDados logs = new DAL.ProcessaDados();
            strPesq1 = logs.PesquisaDados(paramInic);

            BLL.EnviaDados sendData = new BLL.EnviaDados();
            retApiExt = sendData.EnviaRequisicaoApiExterna(strPesq1);

            return retApiExt;
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101. Quase sempre que trava perde a vantagem que tinha e pode criar outros problemas. E usar *thread* é extramente complicado, você deve evitar até ser absolutamente necessário, até mesmo os experientes erram muito fazendo isto. Inclusive porque o código poderia ser mais eficiente para melhorar a performance sem precisar de *thread*, não é muito, mas tem coisas custosas que não precisava fazer. Nem sei se é necessário ou precisa de travamento, a pergunta não deixa claro a real situação.

Comment: Obrigado pelo apontamento Maniero, basicamente preciso que a minha API rode sequencialmente no servidor (FIFO) ou que rode paralelamente no servidor sem que um processamento interfira no outro...

Comment: Você utiliza algum conceito arquitetural da aplicação? CQRS?

Comment: Julio Borges, basicamente faço uso apenas do conceito de camadas, como meu prazo esta relativamente curto estou criando uma aplicação no servidor que irá gerenciar a fila. Obrigado.

Comment: O problema não está na rotina do `ProcessaDados()`? Suponho que ela gera a massa para a `PesquisaDados()`, porém você estaria gerando uma massa diferente , ao receber uma nova requisição antes de ter pesquisado a primeira?