# Atualizar main form após de fechar a load form

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

O que estou a tentar fazer é, preciso de abrir outra form em outra thread onde tem um progress bar que é indeterminated, e na main ui preciso de atualizar a datagrid com os dados da bd após o load acabar.

```cs
 private async void Disp_data_Sim()
        {
            var windowToOpen = new WaitingWorker()
            {
                Owner = this,
            };

            await Task.Run(new Action(() =>
            {
                this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {

                    windowToOpen.ShowDialog();
                });
                try
                {
                    var tempCon = File.ReadAllText("DBConnection.json");
                    var tempCon1 = Crypt.Decrypt(tempCon, "encryption");
                    var sqlInfo = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<SQLInfo>(tempCon1);
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlInfo.GetConString()))
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                        {
                            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT referencia,descricao,pr_custo1,etiqueta,qtd FROM Etiquetas Where etiqueta = @etiqueta";
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@etiqueta", 'S');
                            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
                            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                            da.Fill(dtbl);

                            dataGridView1.Invoke(new Action(() => dataGridView1.DataSource = dtbl));
                        }
                        con.Close();

                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {

                    windowToOpen.Close();
                });
            }));
        }
```

O problema é o seguinte, ele executa outra form mas usa a primaria logo o programa fica "indisponível".

Comment: Procure por `async` este jeito de fazer é ultrapassado e difícil. Em alguns casos a tentativa por sair pela culatra e ficar pior: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101

Comment: Eu não quero ganhar rapidez, o que eu quero é não olhar para o programa que não responde durante 10-15seg enquanto o programa vai buscar tudo a bd.

Answer (score 0):

Eu utilizo algo parecido, tenho um form que exibe uma imagem gif com uma mensagem de aguarde para o cliente.

O que eu faço nesse caso é abrir o formulário de aguarde com `.Show()` e não `ShowModal()`. E quando quiser terminar a execução, você pode dar um `Dispose()` no formulário.

Ficaria basicamente assim (não testei):

```
private async void Disp_data_Sim()
{
    var windowToOpen = new WaitingWorker()
    {
        Owner = this,
    };

    windowToOpen.Show();

    try
    {
        var tempCon = File.ReadAllText("DBConnection.json");
        var tempCon1 = Crypt.Decrypt(tempCon, "encryption");
        var sqlInfo = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<SQLInfo>(tempCon1);
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlInfo.GetConString()))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT referencia,descricao,pr_custo1,etiqueta,qtd FROM Etiquetas Where etiqueta = @etiqueta";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@etiqueta", 'S');
                DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dtbl);

                dataGridView1.Invoke(new Action(() => dataGridView1.DataSource = dtbl));
            }
            con.Close();
        }

        windowToOpen.Close();
        //---- ou  windowToOpen.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Como você tem apenas um progressbar indeterminated essa solução já vai resolver.

Porém, caso queira colocar um progressbar que realmente seja atualizado em conjunto com as informações que são processadas no form de origem (ou em um método externo qualquer), você precisará de trabalhar com `INotifyPropertyChanged` para atualizar as posições do progressbar.